# on Click trigger CTRL+s browser event

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser

I am trying to implement <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> event to pop up "save as" window in browser when I click on button. But it's not working. Please suggest how can I save complete webpage when user click on button.
Below is the code:

```
$( '#save_as' ).bind( "click", function() {
        var e = jQuery.Event( "keypress", { which: 115, ctrlKey:true} );
        jQuery(window).trigger( e );
        alert("Ctrl-S pressed !!!");
});
```

Comment: AFAIK you can't open Save as dialog in javascript.

Comment: any reference related to save as dialog?

Comment: @LinkinTED the problem is not generating the keypress. See the link in my other comment

Answer (score -1):

It works!
Look at a live example: http://codesheet.org/codesheet/346fJMrz

```
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){   
    $(window).keypress(function(event) {
      if (!(event.which == 115 && event.ctrlKey) && !(event.which == 19)) return true;


          setTimeout(function() {

              alert('Ctrl + s is pressed');

              //$("#safeformbtn").click();                      //click some button....
              //$("#postform form input[name=submit]").click(); //click some button....

          }, 200);

        event.preventDefault();
          return false;

      });
  });
})(jQuery);
```